# Mockito: pass mocked object as parameter to a function (when call the function)

Tags: junit, mockito

I am using [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) to write a simple unit test.

I have a function to test:

```
public void doSomething() {
  foo.getStudent(new School());
}
```

My test case:

```
@Test
public void testDoSomething() {
   Foo mockedFoo = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);
   School mockedSchool = Mockito.mock(School.class);
   // I want to pass the mocked school as parameter when food.getStudent(school) is called
   // how to pass mocked school to method?
   when(mockedFoo.getStudent(???)) 

   // run the method under test
   myService.doSomething();
}
```

I want to pass the `mockedSchool` as parameter when `foo.getStudent(school)` is called, how to declare this in Mockito?

Seems Mockito only has `when(...).thenReturn()`, but is there something like `when(...).thenPassArgument(mockedObject)` ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the way you instantiate the School class in the doSomething method; as you instantiate it on the spot you can't overload that instantiation with the mock using mockito.

If you pass it as a parameter of doSomething you should be able to perform this.

I believe PowerMock can help you if you want to overload an internal construction.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't need to assert into the `School` instance and just pass a mocked instance as a parameter, you can do the following:

```java
mockedBar.getStudent(Mockito.isA(School.class));
```

Please read the [Mockito](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html) documentation about the `isA(java.lang.Class<T> clazz)` [method](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Matchers.html#isA(java.lang.Class)).